# Dell Inspiron 15 7000 Gaming : Screen Error After Waking up

Tags: display, dell-inspiron

I have a problem with my laptop
When I sleep the laptop after doing anything and reopen it the display becomes a bunch of vertical lines and works well when I restart but this happened two days ago and keeps happening till now
My laptop is still new 
It's (Dell Inspiron 15 7000 Gaming)

Vertical Lines Photo:
[image: Vertical Lines Photo]

Comment: What video driver do you use ? Try uninstalling the nVidia video driver and see if the problem persists.

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer on another website. BIOS needs updating. I have tested this and it worked. Click the link below download and install the BIOS update

[Dell Inspiron 14 7000 and 15 7000 Gaming System BIOS](http://www.dell.com/support/home/uk/en/ukbsdt1/drivers/driversdetails?driverId=RCC7H&fileId=1964616706&osCode=WT64A&productCode=inspiron-15-7567-laptop&languageCode=en&categoryId=BI)